# Error 500 on webserver but not local host

Tags: php, apache

I have a website that is working on my local machine and works on one set of webhosting but when I move it to the secure intranet that it needs to be placed on I get a server 500 error.

If I simplify the problem the server is not handling includes properly so I have put all content into the php page and I directly go to the GET part that is broken I put https://192.168.2.252/searchbysurname.php?q=morris in the address bar. This works on my normal localhost. I cant access the console logs on the server.

Search by Surname.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$q = ($_GET['q']);


# Connect 
$dbc = @mysqli_connect ( '*******', '*********', '*******', '********')
OR die ( mysqli_connect_error() ) ;
mysqli_set_charset( $dbc, 'utf8' ) ; 


$q1="SELECT employees.employeeid, employees.firstname, employees.surname FROM employees  where UCASE(employees.surname) LIKE UCASE('%".$q."%')";
$r1 = mysqli_query($dbc,$q1);
echo "<table class = 'CSSTableGenerator'>";
while($row1    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r1))
{
    echo "
    <tr><td>" . $row1['firstname'] . "</td><td>" . $row1['surname'] . "</td>
    <td><input type='button' value='View' onclick='viewresults(" . $row1['employeeid'] . ")'></td>
    <td><input type='button' value='Edit' onclick='editresults(" . $row1['employeeid'] . ")'></td>
    </div></td></tr>
    ";
}
echo "</table>";?>
<div id="mainpart"><b></b></div></div>
```

Comment: which 500 http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find out when I can only access the console on the browser I am trying to load the file in (have tried chrome and firebug and cant figure out how to get more info from either) and not the console on the webserver.

Comment: why you even need console for that?  just open in url, try turning on error on php.ini file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the server in the intranet can have a different configuration?
Does it have mysqli for instance?
try to run a simple script with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` both on local and intranet server and compare...

Comment: Thank you. The whole mysqli section is missing. Now I just need to figure out how to put it on - uncommenting the php ini file didnt help :-(